# How Sort data from database in php when using while in php

Tags: php, database, sorting, mysqli

I want to sort date, time from the database from new to old ( high to low ) and I use this code but didn't work! 
can you help me?
and I want MySqli Solution and it uses while because I don't know how many numbers of information I will receive from the database!

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE seller='$id' ORDER BY dtime ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $ordernumber = $row['ordernumber'];  
        echo "<ul> <li> $ordernumber</li></ul>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work"?  Did it error out?  Did it simply fail to sort?  Did it sort incorrectly?  What are your trying to accomplish?

Comment: it sort from low to high

Comment: use `DESC` instead of `ASC` in your mysql query

Comment: Use `.. dtime DESC`

Comment: thank you it works! DESC

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get more details for ordering then click [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html).

In your code, you should write like this below,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE seller='$id' ORDER BY dtime DESC";
```

And please do some search for ordering for your doubt.

Thanks..!!